# Find the extension of a file using php

Tags: php, file-extension

What is the simple way to find the file extension in php, if the filename is filename.jpg.txt?

Comment: you think this has never been asked before? did you search? can you see the *related* list on the right?

Answer (score 4):

you can use the pathinfo function that will provide useful info about the file path, including the extension

http://php.net/pathinfo

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting the string with `explode(".", $string);` and then checking the last element of the array that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
function file_extension($filename)
{
    $path_info = pathinfo($filename);
    return $path_info['extension'];
}
```

Use this function get the file's actual type